# Missing required iOS icon in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I am using the [App Icon Template 4.1](http://appicontemplate.com/ios8) As far as I can tell, I met all of the requirements. What am I doing wrong!? (Beside apples instructions, I checked the other questions here on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) about these icons and followed their instructions but it is still not working…)

### Xcode appIcon asset catalog:

[image: Xcode appIcon asset catalog]

### Xcode error when submitting to the Appstore:

[image: Xcode error when submitting to the Appstore]

### image file names of the appIcons:

[image: image file names of the appIcons v2]

## Update1:

removing the CarPlay Icon doesn't help…

### content.json file:

(which comes with [App Icon Template 4.1](http://appicontemplate.com/ios8) )

```
    {
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-1.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x-1.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-40@2x-1.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-40@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-60@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-60@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-40.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-50.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-50@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "72x72",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-72.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "72x72",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-72@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-76.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-76@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "car",
      "size" : "120x120",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "pre-rendered" : true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Carplay Icon its not needed. Seems to mess things up when its added.

Can you check the dimensons of these files are correct:

```
Icon-76@2x.png is 152x152
Icon-76.png is 76x76
Icon-72.png is 72x72
Icon.png is 57x57
```

If this doesnt work can you post the contents of the contents.json file?

Comment: also added the dimensions to the "image file names of the appIcons"

Comment: Could you try generating them with this http://imageresier-agrastas.rhcloud.com/ just to rule out the sizes and filenames

Comment: Also in Xcode have you set the "Use Asset Catalog" under General > App Icons and launch Images > App Icon Source

Comment: Also check that the asset catalog is added to the target. click on asset catalog in xcode > right hand menu click on page icon > target Membership > make sure your target is ticked.

Comment: where you able to check the target membership?

Comment: Yes thank you - I am using Spritebuilder which apparently sets the target wrong when creating an asset catalog for the app icon. After fixing that I still had to remove the car play icon though.

Comment: Yeah the car play icon always seems to break it, you can select the Asset catalog and de-select the car play setting on the right hand side menu to remove it, just to clean it up abit.